# ReactJS: registros.map is not a function

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, function, map

[image: registros.map is not a function]estoy usando react y Mysql. Lo que quiero es mostrar los registros de mi base de datos, especificamente de una tabla llamada 'nacionals'. Hago uso de una API (ThunderClient) y si me muestra los registros de dicha tabla. Incluso en la consola del navegador si me devuelve dicho arreglo con la información, pero al querer imprimirlo en una tabla, (para que ya sea visible en la página como tal) me dice que registros .map, nos es una función, he visto problemas similares pero como tal, cada uno es provocado por diferentes razones, las cuales ya he verificado y probado y ninguna ha resultado, ojalá me pudieran ayudar, el código es el siguiente, de antemano, gracias

```html
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const url='http://localhost:8000/nacionals/'

const CompShowRegN=()=>{
    const [registros, setRegistro]= useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getRegistros()
    },[] )
    //Mostrar reg
    const getRegistros = async () => {
        try {
        const res= await axios.get(url)
        console.log("Respuesta de la API:", res.data);
        setRegistro(res.data);
        

        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.error("Error al obtener datos:", error);
        }

    }

    //Procedimiento para cambiar de color la celda del ID basado en el puntaje
   const getColor = nac_puntaje => {
    if (nac_puntaje >= 10 && nac_puntaje <=25) {
      return '#238900'; // Ejemplo: si el puntaje es >=30, la fila tendrá un color de fondo 
    } else if (nac_puntaje >= 30 && nac_puntaje <=40) {
      return '#599602'; 
    }
    else if (nac_puntaje >= 45 && nac_puntaje <=55) {
        return '#8EB404'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 60 && nac_puntaje <=70) {
        return '#C4C906'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 75 && nac_puntaje <=85) {
        return '#E4C607'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 90 && nac_puntaje <=100) {
        return '#E9A805'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 105 && nac_puntaje <=110) {
        return '#EF8904'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 120 && nac_puntaje <=135) {
        return '#F46B02'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 140 && nac_puntaje <=150) {
        return '#FA4C01'; 
      }
      else if (nac_puntaje >= 155 && nac_puntaje <=170) {
        return '#FF2E00'; 
      }
      
    
    return ''; // Clase por defecto (sin estilos)
  }

    return( //Los estilos de la tabla están en Nacional.css
    <div className='cnt'>
        <div className='fil'>
            <div className='colu'>
                <table className='tabla'>
                    <thead className='tabla-prim'>
                        <tr>
                          <th> # </th>
                          <th>Estado </th>  
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {registros.map ((registro )=> (
                            <tr key={registro.id}>
                            <td style={{ backgroundColor: getColor(registro.nac_puntaje) }}>{registro.id}</td>
                                <td>{registro.nac_estado}</td>


                            </tr>
                        )
                        )}

                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>)
    

}
export default CompShowRegN
```

Comment: Mueve la declaración de esta función `const getRegistros = async () => {...}` dentro de `useEffect`, avísanos del resultado